# What do i put for the return?

Tags: java, eclipse

What am i supposed to put in the *return* statement so that it returns whether you have won, tied, or lost? I have tried to think of everything but I just can't seem to figure it out.

**EDIT:**
Here is all my code for people who wanted it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class RockPaperScissorsClass {

private int wins;
private int losses;
private int ties;
private int CChoice;
private int PChoice;

public RockPaperScissorsClass()
{
    this(0,0,0,0,0);
}

public RockPaperScissorsClass(int wins, int losses, int ties, int computerPick, int playerPick) 
{
    this.wins=wins;
    this.losses=losses;
    this.ties=ties;
    this.CChoice=CChoice;
    this.PChoice=PChoice;
}

public void setPlayer(int p)
{
    CChoice = p;
}

public String getPlayer()
{

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Choice(1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors)-->");
    int PPChoice = in.nextInt();
    String PChoice = null;
    if(PPChoice==1)
    {
        PChoice="Rock";
    }
    else if(PPChoice==2)
    {
        PChoice="Paper";
    }
    else if(PPChoice==3)
    {
        PChoice="Scissors";
    }
    else
    {
        while(true)
        {
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice. Please try again.");
        System.out.println("Enter Choice(1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors)-->");
        PPChoice = in.nextInt();
        if(PPChoice==1)
        {
            PChoice="Rock";
            break;
        }
        else if(PPChoice==2)
        {
            PChoice="Paper";
            break;
        }
        else if(PPChoice==3)
        {
            PChoice="Scissors";
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    return PChoice;
}

public String getComputer()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int CCChoice = rand.nextInt(3)+1;
    String CChoice = null;
    if(CCChoice==1)
    {
        CChoice="Rock";
    }
    else if(CCChoice==2)
    {
        CChoice="Paper";
    }
    else if(CCChoice==3)
    {
        CChoice="Scissors";
    }
    return CChoice;
}




public String determineWinner() 
{
    String detWinner = "";
    if(PChoice==1 && CChoice==2)
    {
        detWinner  = "You Lose";
    }
    else if(PChoice==1 && CChoice==3)
    {
        detWinner = "You Win";
    }
    else if(PChoice==2 && CChoice==3)
    {
        detWinner  = "You Lose";
    }
    else if(PChoice==2 && CChoice==1)
    {
        detWinner = "You Win";
    }
    else if(PChoice==3 && CChoice==1)
    {
        detWinner  = "You Lose";
    }
    else if(PChoice==3 && CChoice==2)
    {
        detWinner = "You Win";
    }
    else if(PChoice==1 && CChoice==1)
    {
        detWinner = "You Have Tied";
    }
    else if(PChoice==2 && CChoice==2)
    {
        detWinner = "You Have Tied";
    }
    else if(PChoice==3 && CChoice==3)
    {
        detWinner = "You Have Tied";
    }

    return detWinner;

}

}
```

Comment: try like this `retrunString="" if(condition){returnString="someVal"}else if(condition){returnString="some other value"}return returnString"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
public class RockPaperScissorsClass {

    private int wins;
    private int losses;
    private int ties;
    private int CChoice;
    private int PChoice;

    public RockPaperScissorsClass() {
        this(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public RockPaperScissorsClass(int wins, int losses, int ties, int computerPick, int playerPick) {
        this.wins = wins;
        this.losses = losses;
        this.ties = ties;
        this.CChoice = computerPick;
        this.PChoice = playerPick;
    }

    public void setPlayer(int p) {
        CChoice = p;
    }

    public String getPlayer() {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Choice(1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors)-->");
        int PPChoice = in.nextInt();
        String PChoice = null;
        if (PPChoice == 1) {
            this.PChoice = 1;
            PChoice = "Rock";
        } else if (PPChoice == 2) {
            this.PChoice = 2;
            PChoice = "Paper";
        } else if (PPChoice == 3) {
            this.PChoice = 3;
            PChoice = "Scissors";
        } else {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice. Please try again.");
                System.out.println("Enter Choice(1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors)-->");
                PPChoice = in.nextInt();
                if (PPChoice == 1) {
                    PChoice = "Rock";
                    break;
                } else if (PPChoice == 2) {
                    PChoice = "Paper";
                    break;
                } else if (PPChoice == 3) {
                    PChoice = "Scissors";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return PChoice;
    }

    public String getComputer() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int CCChoice = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        System.out.println(CCChoice);
        String CChoice = null;
        if (CCChoice == 1) {
            this.CChoice = 1; 
            CChoice = "Rock";
        } else if (CCChoice == 2) {
            this.CChoice = 2;
            CChoice = "Paper";
        } else if (CCChoice == 3) {
            this.CChoice = 3;

            CChoice = "Scissors";
        }
        return CChoice;
    }

    public String determineWinner() {
        String detWinner = "";
        if (PChoice == 1 && CChoice == 2) {
            detWinner = "You Lose";
        } else if (PChoice == 1 && CChoice == 3) {
            detWinner = "You Win";
        } else if (PChoice == 2 && CChoice == 3) {
            detWinner = "You Lose";
        } else if (PChoice == 2 && CChoice == 1) {
            detWinner = "You Win";
        } else if (PChoice == 3 && CChoice == 1) {
            detWinner = "You Lose";
        } else if (PChoice == 3 && CChoice == 2) {
            detWinner = "You Win";
        } else if (PChoice == 1 && CChoice == 1) {
            detWinner = "You Have Tied";
        } else if (PChoice == 2 && CChoice == 2) {
            detWinner = "You Have Tied";
        } else if (PChoice == 3 && CChoice == 3) {
            detWinner = "You Have Tied";
        }

        return detWinner;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RockPaperScissorsClass rc = new RockPaperScissorsClass();
        System.out.println("Player is: " + rc.getPlayer());
        System.out.println("Computer is: " + rc.getComputer());
        System.out.println(rc.determineWinner());
    }
}
```

I change a little bit about your code.

Comment: i tried that but when i test in the main it just returns null instead of you won or you lose ect

Comment: try checking your `if` statement, in my code above, it will not print null, it will rather print an empty value string like `""` because I declared `tempStr` to `""` and not `null`.

Comment: i tried your way but it just doesnt print out anything at all

Comment: You can print it by using your method that has a return value that you took on that function. I edited my answer. Check it

Comment: is it necessary that i name it tempStr or can i name it detWinner and it would still work?

Comment: Yes, of course, you name your 'variable' whatever you want.

Comment: i tried this but still nothing comes up. maybe it is because my main is set up  a little bit differently?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  RockPaperScissorsClass s = new RockPaperScissorsClass();
  System.out.println(s.getPlayer());
  System.out.println(s.getComputer());
  String detWinner = s.determineWinner();
  System.out.println(s.determineWinner());
 }

Comment: edit your question and put it there, so others can see too.

Comment: Its impossible, because it works on my unit. try to copy all that in your IDE, unless you are not well learned in java, you wouldn't run it.

Comment: ok it works now thank you. but can you explain why u put "this.PChoice=1; " and the other 2 in there under the getPlayer()? i dont understand why u put that there.

Comment: Its very simple sir @GeorgeFinklesin, its because u need to initialize it according to its number result, for example, you choose 1 and its String value is `Rock`, so how can we know if your `PChoice` has an equivalent value as `Rock` in its number. so we assign `PChoice` = 1 because you choose 1 in the beginning. you need to initialize `PChoice` to 1 because you will need it on your `if conditions` later on, remember your `if (PChoice == 1 && CChoice == 2)` . That is the use of that.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have '???' is the default case if none of your switch statements are met.  At this location I'd suggest you throw an exception as your statements should have by this point reached a decision.

Your println statements are the place where the output value can be returned.  BTW this code looks a bit iffy, perhaps you might consider reorganizing it a bit for your own sanity!
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to create a 2D array containing the outcomes for the various combinations of p and c choices:

```
public class yourClass {
    private static final int[][] results = new int[3][3];
    results[0][0] = 0;
    results[0][1] = -1;
    results[0][2] = 1;
    results[1][0] = 1;
    results[1][1] = 0;
    results[1][2] = -1;
    results[2][0] = -1;
    results[2][1] = 1;
    results[2][2] = 0;

    public String determineWinner(int pChoice, int cChoice) {
        int result = results[pChoice-1][cChoice-1];
        String label = "";

        switch (result) {
            case -1:
                label = "You Lose";
                break;
            case 0:
                label = "You Have Tied";
                break;
            case 1:
                label = "You Win";
                break;
            default:
                label = "Move cannot be determined";
                break;
        }

        return label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` is a good-suited solution in such cases. Also, you can reduce your `if`-`else` chain quite a bit:

```
enum Outcome {
    WIN("You won"),
    LOST("You lost"),
    TIE("You tied");

    private String msg;

    private Outcome(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
}

public Outcome determineWinner(int pChoice, int cChoice) {
    Outcome outcome = null;
    int diff = PChoice - CChoice;
    switch (diff) {
        case -1:
        case 2:
            outcome = Outcome.LOST;
            break;
        case 1:
        case -2:
            outcome = Outcome.WIN;
            break;
        case 0:
            outcome = Outcome.TIE;
            break;
    }
    return outcome;

}
```

It all could be used to determine outcome like that:

```
...
Outcome outcome = determineWinner(pChoice, cChoice);
System.out.println(outcome.getMsg());
...
```